# Alert dialog box button position changes in landscape mode

Tags: android, button, alert

The **buttons** of *alert dialog box* is **changing postion** while changing to landscape mode.
That is in portrait mode  buttons will be OK then Cancel  and in landscape mode Cancel then OK
.Alert box default buttons is used not any custom layouts..
This is noticed in ICS devices
can anyone help?

Comment: May be this link would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301791/positioning-ok-cancel-buttons-so-that-they-mimic-the-layout-in-dialogs

Comment: @Mohan thnkz but the solution there found sounds like creating a custom layout for dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like its a flaw in Android so probably not a lot you can do, except report it. You could make a custom dialog to lay it out properly but involves more work.

Comment: I think it's already reported. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24138

Comment: thnkz.so that means its the default behavior of android and  its not an issue??

Comment: @Mohan, I'm not sure if that's exactly the same, that's just saying they buttons have swapped between android versions whereas the OP is saying the buttons swap when orientation changes

Comment: @Sjk Yes its the default behaviour so not a great issue but is probably a bug that should be resolved by google as it would be a bit confusing for most users especially novices having the buttons one way and then changing orientation swaps them around.

Comment: @Boardy Also the layout,i mean color of dialog is also changed.in portrait mode dialog box is somewhat dark color with title in blue color.and in landscape it was like white dialog box like old version of android(2.3)..Is that behaviour is also default..Now iam using android 4.1. on basis of this i am asking this..i forgot to mention version before.

Comment: Oh that's strange, not noticed that before, as far as I know you can change the style of an AlerDialog, are you sure your not applying any themes somewhere, either code or in the manifest file. Not even sure if its possible to do that but the only thing I can think of

Comment: @Boardy ya sorry theme was there..but now i changed it to same ie both mode have same theme.Then also position of the buttons are changed